# apply condition to the optimized parameters using optim

Tags: r, optimization

Suppose I want to optimise the a vector of parameters `x` using the function below

```
fr <- function(x) {   
    x1 <- x[1]
    x2 <- x[2]
    x3 <- x[2]
    x4 <- x[2]
    100 * (x2 - x1 * x1)^2 + (1 - x1)^2 + x3 + x4
 }

temp <- optim(c(1, 1.5, 1.8, 1.9), fr)
```

The `x` being optimised cannot be sorted i.e. they have a natural order to them with first element of `x` being always the smallest and last element being always the largest. I want to retain these after optimisation as well.
After the optimisation is done, the optimised parameters are as follows:

```
temp$par
[1] 0.3334119 0.1011343 3.2182704 2.7068277
```

Is there anyway I can apply a condition to the optimised parameters such that they are in an ascending order i.e. following condition is satisfied

```
temp$par[1] < temp$par[2] < temp$par[3] < temp$par[4]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sort `x` in `fr` and then use `sort(temp$par)` as the result. Note that `par` here does *not* correspond to `x` in the question.  `x` in the question corresponds to `x` in `fr` and also to `sort(tmep$par)` here so that the calculation in `fr` only works with ordered `x` values.

```
fr <- function(par) {   
    x <- sort(par)
    x1 <- x[1]
    x2 <- x[2]
    x3 <- x[2]
    x4 <- x[2]
    100 * (x2 - x1 * x1)^2 + (1 - x1)^2 + x3 + x4
 }

temp <- optim(c(1, 1.5, 1.8, 1.9), fr)

temp$convergence
## [1] 0

x <- sort(temp$par); x
## [1] 0.9898021 0.9898025 1.9933419 2.0045291
```

Comment: Actually the `x` being optimised cannot be sorted i.e. they have a natural order to them with first element of `x` being always the smallest and last element being the largest. I want to retain these after optimisation as well.

Comment: understood. thank you for your time and explaination

Comment: Have transferred comments to answer.